# Phone number doesn't get validated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form everything get validated except phone number i tried and tried without any success, i can figure out where the problem lay

Here is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cell, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
       <div class="col-md-4">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cell, new { @class = "form-control", id = "Cell", placeholder = "Phone Number" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cell, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })  
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    jQuery(document)
        .ready(function () {

            jQuery("#Cell").inputmask("099 999 9999");

            jQuery("#Cell")
                .on("blur",
                    function () {
                        var last = $(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1);
                        if (last.length == 4) {
                            var move = $(this).val().substr($(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1);
                            var lastfour = move + last;
                            var first = $(this).val().substr(0, 9);
                            $(this).val(first + '-' + lastfour);
                        }
                    });  

        });
</script>
```

Model

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
    [MinLength(10)]
    [StringLength(13, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]
    public string Cell { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the current behavior you are experiencing and what is the expected behavior ?

Comment: @Shyju the form mustn't POST if the phone number is less than 10 or there is no number it should  say Please enter a phone number

Comment: It is easier to get a response, if you format your code to fit without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I got it this is what i did on a model and View

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a Phone Number")]
        [Display(Name = "Cell")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
        public string Cell { get; set; }


@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cell, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id="Cell", placeholder = "Phone Number" } })
```